# I would like to know if i can remove an image when button is clicked in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to remove the image when I click 1 key.

```py
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
import random

# Intialise pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)  # Fullscreen
```

**Cards**

```
cards = (pygame.image.load('image/london.png'), pygame.image.load('image/america.png'))

def card():
    screen.blit(card_size[0], (100, 40))
    screen.blit(card_size[1], (330, 40))
```

**Game loop**

loop of the program starts here

```py
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill((255, 194, 102))  # RGB
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # Event handler
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Here I have tried to remove item from the list but is didn't work.

```py
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == ord('1'):
            cards.remove()
        if event.key == ord('2'):
            print('gone')

card()
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Please care about the formatting of your code. See [StackOverflow Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an image means not to draw the image. There are different solutions.

---

Solution 1:

Draw the images in a loop:

```py
cards = [
    pygame.image.load('image/london.png'), 
    pygame.image.load('image/america.png')]
```

```py
def card():
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        screen.blit(cards[i], (100 + i*230, 40))
```

[`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) an image when a key is pressed:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1 and len(cards) > 0:
                cards.pop(0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_2 and len(cards) > 1:
                cards.pop(1)
```

---

Solution 2:

Add a list that indicates if an image needs to be drawn:

```py
cards_active = [True, True]
def card():
    for i in range(len(cards)):
        if cards_active[i]:
            screen.blit(cards[i], (100 + i*230, 40))
```

Toggle the state in the list when a key is pressed:

```py
while running:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_1 and len(cards) > 0:
                cards_active[0] = not cards_active[0]
            if event.key == pygame.K_2 and len(cards) > 1:
                cards_active[1] = not cards_active[1]
```

Comment: I tried using both methods but it shoes an error

Comment: Thanks so much for the help but In the first solution, it says "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'" and in the second one it says "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @Shreyas I see. `cards` must be a list: `cards = [pygame.image.load('image/london.png'), pygame.image.load('image/america.png')]`. `[]` instead of `()`. `()` is for tuples, but `[]` is for lists. I've add this to the answer.

Comment: Legend, Thank you so much.

Comment: @Shreyas Thank you. Is the answer acceptable?